# Google Tag manager: How do I restrict GA Events to just one div (and containing elements)?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

How do I configure the rules in Google Tag Manager if I want to restrict the Click-Events to just an element and its subelement?
I've found https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/3420054?hl=en#ClicksOnLinks 
But I can't see how I setup a rule to restrict the events.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is propably to assign a class name or an id to the element. This will be accessible trough the element classes or element id macro (those macros will be set up automatically by GTM). You can then create a rule "fire where event equals *gtm.click* and element.classes contains *myclass*".

Answer (score 0):

Jerry, create an **click listener** according to the [manual you linked](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/3420054?hl=en#ClicksOnLinks).

Then, to track all click on elements and its subelements, custom macro and a bit of jQuery is probably the best way to go. Consider this *Custom JS macro* that would return 'nav' string if a clicked element has an ancestor with the ID *nav*.

```
function() {
  var el = {{element}};
  while (el && el !== document.body && el.id !== 'nav') {
    el = el.parentElement;
  }
  return el.id === 'nav';
}
```

I have seen this on Google Product Forum, but I couldn't find the post itself. To give a proper credit though, it was posted by Brian Kuhn (Tech Lead for GTM).

Using these two macro-based rules should then do the trick:

1. *{{event}}* equals *gtm.Click*
2. *{{element id}}* contains *nav*

Hope this helps!